# Memcache , python client doesnt distribute the keys among all of the servers in the pool

Tags: memcached

I have 7 webservers with 64gb of ram each, I want to make use some of this 64 gb of ram with memcached, so I assigned 30gb to memcache in each webservers and added all of the 7 servers to the memcache servers list on my app, All fine till now except that only 3 of the servers gets utilized as seen in the screenshot, I double checked that telnet 11211 works on all of the servers from any other server in the pool.

[image]

Comment: Take a look http://serverfault.com/questions/282756/memcache-issues-in-a-distributed-environment-with-many-nodes

Comment: @FedericoSierra this doesnt seem to be the case, my 4 servers doent get used at all. Having all of the 600k hash keys to be similar between them seems kinda impossible.  looking at the implementation of the memcached package the servers gets selected with  server = self.buckets[serverhash % len(self.buckets)]

Comment: I'm not expert, but not seem a consistent hashing, maybe you can try with a more advanced memcached lib like [pylibmc](http://sendapatch.se/projects/pylibmc/)

Comment: switched to pylibmc and the problem got solved, I guess there is a bug or something in the client I was using...